# How Simply Expanded Variable Assignment Matters?

Tags: makefile, variable-assignment

I couldn't understand how **Simply Expanded Variable Assignment** is different from **Recursively Expanded Variable Assignment**. And get three questions on the following code -

1. Why `make echo_RT_LIM` shows **RT_LIM** updated value, but `SUB_R` doesn't?
2. If **SUB_R** uses **Simply Expanded Variable Assignment** - **:=**, is there a way to allow user reassign the value of **RT_LIM** and reflect the updated value in the early defined target - **runsim**.
3. According gnu make manual, a disadvantage for **Recursively Expanded Variable Assignment** is for Transforming Text Functions case that makes **make** run slower, can you elaborate it by giving a simple example?

As following gnu make manual suggestion by using **Simply Expanded Variable Assignment**, I came across the problem list as **item 2**. But if using **Recursively Expanded Variable Assignment**, will it bring any side effect in this case? Will it still allow user to override the **RT_LIM** afterwards so that **SUB_R** is configurable by reassign **RT_LIM**?

```
RT_LIM ?= 08:00:00
SUB_R := $(RT_LIM)
SUB_L = $(RT_LIM)

echo_%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)

runsim:
    @echo SUB_R: $(SUB_R)
    @echo SUB_L: $(SUB_L)

# reassign to different value afterwards, such as in a different included file
RT_LIM = 09:00:00
```

Comment: Can any folks bring some light on it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question exactly: the examples you show seem pretty clear.

This line:

```
bar = 1
FOO = $(bar)
```

means that when make stores the value of the `FOO` variable internally, the textual value is literally `$(bar)` because in recursive variables the value is not expanded when it's assigned.

This line:

```
bar = 1
FOO := $(bar)
```

means that the textual value of the `FOO` variable internally is `1` because it was expanded when it was assigned.

So then later on when `$(FOO)` is expanded, in the first case it will expand to whatever the value of `bar` is AT THAT TIME.  In the second case it will always expand to `1` regardless of what the value of `bar` is (because `$(bar)` no longer appears in the variable value).

Comment: Good to hear from you, MadScientist. Your explanation makes me clearer. I am facing a problem if there is a way to allow user reassign $(bar) afterwards and pass to FOO in the following case. bar = 1
FOO := $(bar). If using FOO = $(bar) is the solution, will it bring the problem mentioned in manual that make run slower?

Comment: I don't really understand that question.  If you have a specific use case in mind, then you should edit your question and ask about _that_, including a minimal reproducible example formatted as a code block, instead of a generic one: SO is about helping people who have a concrete problem solve that problem, it's not really intended for abstract questions.  I will say is that premature optimization is the root of most of the evil in software so you should not be scared by that comment in the manual unless you have reason to believe it will matter.  Useful is better than fast.

Comment: I hope that my reply didn't make you mad, MadScientist. I was having difficult to understand the recursive assignment(=) and conditional recursive assignemnt( ?=). Can you help me understand why make echo_RT_LIM shows RT_LIM updated value(2nd time assignment) although the assignment is after the target echo_RT_LIM. It seems the order of recursive assignment has no dependency on the target definition location in the code. That make me confusion on the Make language with other program language such as C. In C language the variable assignment and printf its value location are highly dependent.

Comment: That's correct, it does not.  The important thing is when the recursive variable is _expanded_, not when it's assigned.  First the entire makefile is parsed.  After that, `SUB_L` has the value `$(RT_LIM)` and `RT_LIM` has the value `09:00:00`.  Then your recipe is invoked, and `$(SUB_L)` expands to `$(RT_LIM)` which expands to `09:00:00`.  You are 100% correct that you cannot consider a makefile to be a procedural language like C, or a scripting language like shell or Python or Perl.  Makefiles are nothing like those and you will only confuse yourself if you try to think of them like that.

Comment: If you want variables that behave like the ones you're used to in C, then that is what simply-expanded variables do.  If you want to try to apply C paradigms to Makefiles, then you can consider that a recursive variable is like a pointer to a value, and expanding that recursive variable is like indirecting through the pointer to get the value.  The result is whatever the value is when you indirect the pointer, not what it was when you assigned the pointer.  A simple variable is like a normal, non-pointer variable: it always has that value.

Comment: If you have not read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html yet then you definitely need to do that.

Comment: Finally it helps out. I read the make manual as you pointed. It is exactly what I need. Great help, MadScientist.